# importing issue for jsdom package for jest testing framework

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jsdom

I am getting TextEncoder error message when testing a div created by jsdom package using Jest framework.
I am having below node.js and jsdom version :

Node.js version: v16.17.0
jsdom version: v22.1.0

Below is my configuration code

1. jest configuration :

```
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [],
};
```

2. babel configuration :

```
{
  "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }]]
}
```

3. Test case code :

```
require('text-encoding').TextEncoder;

import jsdom from 'jsdom';
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

function myFunction(element) {
  console.log(element.width);
  if (element.width) {
    return 'success';
  }
  else {
    return 'failed';
  }
}

describe("Test myFunction", () => {
  it("should return the uppercase content of the passed element", () => {
    const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><html><body></body></html>`, {
      runScripts: "dangerously",
      resources: "usable"
    });
    const { document, window } = dom.window;
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.width = '500px';
    div.height = '500px';
    const result = myFunction(div);
    expect(result).toBe('success');
  });
});
```

I tried to install the text encoder package but still getting same issue.